# How can I include a php language file and display ü instead of �?

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I have a php file named `german_lang.php`:

```
$lang['ABOUT_US'] = 'Über uns';
```

and I include it into my `index.php`:

```
<?php 
   include_once 'german_lang.php';
?>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
   <?php echo $lang['ABOUT_US']; ?> 
</body>
```

But my result is:

�ber uns

The result I wish to have is:

Über uns

Comment: german_lang.php file must be UTF-8, check with notepad++ Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lang['ABOUT_US'] = 'Über uns';
```

copy/paste this... is in utf-8

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you copy that text from a file in ANSI .. and display in utf-8 will not show properly. what editor do you use ?

Comment: I am using TextWrangler

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/152001 and copy $lang['ABOUT_US'] = 'Über uns'; from my answer

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with this language "iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 < file > file.new" it is something you write in the Terminal right?

Comment: yes, file is german_lang.php ... and file.new should be german_lang_utf-8.php

Comment: Ah, now I have the solution! Thank you! I did it like that. I deleted the file and created a new file directly on the server. This file was automatically utf-8 and then it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML encoded version:

```
&Uuml;
```

That is, in `german_lang.php`:

```
$lang['ABOUT_US'] = '&Uuml;ber uns';
```

Alternatively, you could add

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

to the top of your file to change it to recognize Unicode characters.

Comment: No, this is not possible, I will have a lot of text to include, and I cannot change in every text the ü to &Uuml;

Comment: Why not just use `str_replace` to hit them all at once? The issue is that your browser is seeing an ASCII file rather than a Unicode one and so doesn't know what that character is.

Comment: Yes thank you, I will try, but I am really confused, that there is no other way to recognize utf-8 for php

Comment: Edited with another way that might work better for you.

Comment: I put this on my index.php page but still the result is �ber uns

Answer (score 0):

try it...

```
    $str="Über uns";
$str=htmlspecialchars($str);
    $lang['ABOUT_US'] = $str;
     echo htmlspecialchars($str);
```

this function may help you

Comment: I tried <?php echo htmlspecialchars($lang['ABOUT_US']); ?>  on my index.php, but I get an empty result

Comment: Thank you, this works, why is the shorter version not working?

Comment: try $lang['About_US']=htmlspecialchars('Über uns');

Comment: This is not working inside that file, I get an empty result+

Comment: Actually your answer is not working for me, because the sting "Über uns" is not on my index.php page. It is on my german_lang.php page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123347/discussion-between-klajdi-dosti-and-jarla).